# Does the Mold do percentage or a fixed number of damage over time?

Tags: control

Does the Mold do percentage or a fixed number of damage over time?

I'm trying to get through the Hidden Area in Research where it seems like the whole room is full of Mold...

I'm assuming it is, but I want to know if grabbing Health Mods would help or if it doesn't matter since it deals % of my health every second so I have as long as I would ever have to survive.

Well, Immortality assist keeps the room from killing me, so that's nice.

Answer (score 1):

While it's not a direct answer to your question - you can make the question moot by doing the side mission "Old Growth" where after you acquire some samples for her Dr Raya Underhill will synthesize you pill that grants immunity to the effects of the Mold.

You still have to watch out for the infected Mold host enemies of course but you won't take damage simply from being in a mold-infested space.

Comment: Yep. Did the quest early. Needed to wait until I almost had the LV6 Card to get the pill. ... Now this is just a curiosity for those who want to get things early and stuff.